# Поиск библиотеки для отрисовки 2D графики в C# и WPF, аналогичной QGraphicsView в Qt

Tags: c#, wpf, библиотеки, 2d

Я недавно начал работать с C# и WPF после опыта работы с Python и PySide6. В Qt я часто использовал виджет QGraphicsView для отрисовки графики, который предоставлял удобные функции, такие как адаптация размеров под содержимое, масштабирование и панорамирование. Однако, я обнаружил, что стандартный canvas в WPF не так удобен в использовании.
Я хотел бы узнать, существуют ли библиотеки для C# и WPF, которые предлагают функциональность, аналогичную QGraphicsView в Qt? Мне нужно добавить на форму виджет и отрисовывать в нем простую 2D графику (простые чертежи, схемы). Буду благодарен за любые рекомендации. Спасибо!

Comment: Что именно означает "не так удобен"? Qt в глаза не видел, поэтому не понимаю, что вы хотите. Быть может вам вообще канвас не нужен, исходя из вопроса непонятно. Конкретизируйте вопрос. Какая именно задача решается?

Comment: Добрый день. Задача следующая. Программа осуществляет расчеты и на основе расчетов, строит чертеж в масштабе 1:1. Средние размеры чертежа 5000 на 7000 мм. Соотвествено нужен контрол, в котором можно этот чертеж отрисовать. Контрол должен автоматически подстраиватся под размеры чертежа, иметь возможность масштабироватся, панорамирование(иметь полосы прокрутки), такжы у нас должна быть возможность регулировать видимость нарисованых объектов на форме(есть чертеж, а есть его размеры отображение размеров должно включатся и выключатся по чекбоксу).

Comment: Так бы сразу https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495171/12888024 Чтобы была прокрутка, положите канвас в `ScrollViewer` с подстраиванием под размеры и зумами может помочь `ViewBox`.